# Question about Permutation Sets (Groups and Symmetries)

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, permutations

Let $a = (123)(456)$ in $S_{10}$. Find the highest possible order of a permutation $b$ in $S_{10}$ such that $b^k=a$ for some $k$.

Attempt: I already know that there are only two possible cases for b. The first case in which the disjoint cycle form of b contains a 6-cycle, and the second case in which b contains exactly two 3-cycles (and perhaps some other cycles that aren't 3-cycles). I've already tried a few examples of each case but how would I know if I've attained a maximum order one? For the first case I have one example which is any permutation that contains $(142536)$ whose square is a. And in the second case all I can think of are the permutations that contain a itself. Are there any others?

Comment: please use  double"$",.

Comment: Does it help that $\text{ord}(b)$ has to divide $k\text{ord}(a)=3k$, thus $\text{ord}(b)$ be a multiple of $3$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $$x=(a_1,a_2...,a_6)(b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4)$$

Notice that $|x|=12$ and $$x^4=(a_1,a_5,a_3)(a_2,a_6,a_4)$$

So chosse $x=(1,4,3,6,2,5)(7,8,9,10)$.